# Delete duplicate rows in calc?

Tags: duplicates, openoffice-calc

I have a column in openoffice calc with a set of codes.  For example:

```
B1
B1
Br
Bh
Ht
C3
C3
```

So what I would like to do is delete all the duplicates so I am left with just:

```
Br
Bh
Ht
```

Any help much appreciated.

Cheers

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Select the entire range containing data to filter, then click on the menu

Data > Filter > Standard Filter

and:

1. Use a condition that is always TRUE, like field1 = Not empty
2. Click on the button more, select Remove Duplicate, select Copy to and put the address of an empty cell
   The whole range (without duplicate) will be analyzed and copied at that new address.

[source](https://forum.openoffice.org/en/forum/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=5379)

Or

For both Calc and Excel the quick and dirty solution would be

=COUNTIF($A:$A;$A1)
copied down for every entry in Column A.

All entries where the result is 1 can be filtered as new values.

Calc syntax for COUNTIF:

[Source](http://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/How_Tos/Calc%3a_COUNTIF_function)