# Libre Office Spreadsheet- How to retain only one value among many duplicate values in a column?

Tags: duplicates, libreoffice-calc

There is a column with many duplicate values, I want to filter out all duplicate values but still keeping a single value among the duplicates.
For eg -If my column has

```
[a,b,a,a,a,b,c,c,d]
```

then I want result to be like -

```
[a,b,c,d].
```

How can I do this?

UPATE - I don't want to remove all duplicates , I want to get one value of each duplicate.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Delete duplicate rows in calc?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22511660/delete-duplicate-rows-in-calc). See also http://askubuntu.com/a/502897/20661

Answer (score 0):

Solved by using IF() formula in another column